# Does a getter with a different return type qualify as a getter?

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have a variable called

`List<String> names;`

if i have a method like

`Iterator getNames()
{
return names.iterator();
}`

Is it technically still a getter method because i changed it to Iterator?

Comment: I am asking because this is not showing under code that is covered by my unit tests. So i am in a dilemma whether i need to write a unit test case for it or not? Because we generally do not write test cases for Getters and Setters right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the JDK allows this, its not a good idea to do it.

For one, there are conventions based off of the naming of your methods, that have some dependencies on them.

1. JavaBean objects use getters and setters to set bean properties. If they disobey the convention, the program will fail. See [JavaBeans spec, section 8.3.1](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/)
2. JSON objects - the JSONObject class uses the accessor methods in the constructor. 
   See: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.Object)
3. Some JPA implementations will incorrectly process your entity classes if they have multiple getters with the same name but different return types.

I bet there are more dependencies, but even if these don't apply to your solution, it's still wise to follow the convention for the sake of readability. You don't want any other developer cursing you sometime in the future for breaking the standards :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a bad idea to me from a design point of view.

I would simply have a getter `public List<String> getNames()`.

For "safe publishing", you should consider returning a *copy* of the list in the implementation:

```
public List<String> getNames() {
    return new ArrayList<String>(names);
}
```

Comment: An [unmodifiable list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) wouldn't be a horrible idea either. It'll stop whoever is calling your getter from thinking they can add/change the names through the `List` they get as opposed to the proper methods in your class.

Comment: Yeah but if we return a List the method which is using this also must be of type list.In future if we change the type of the variable to say array at a later point of time. This would mean that i have to change the getter methods return type. Which in turn would effect the method that is using it.

Answer (score 2):

If you class is going to be introspected by some bean tool, getNames() should return names.
  For clarity, call it what it is:

```
getNamesIterator();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking the otherway around. A method of the form getXxx is a getter. Java conventions don't imply that you must have a field named xxx. This is your class business and encapsulation provides just : the abilit to hide your data struxtures to other classes.

Sorry for typo, mobile..